# Function won't return tuple/list when run in Flask app

Tags: python, flask

**Background**

I'm developing a simple Flask app. I have a function that should return a tuple:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def extract_data(path: str) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, int, pd.DataFrame]:
    csv = pd.read_csv(path):
    data = csv["data"].to_numpy()
    data[np.isnan(data)] = 0
    data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=0)
    bounds = len(csv["bounds"]) - 1
    data = data[data != 0]
    return data, bounds, csv
```

**Problem and Attempts**

If I run this outside of Flask it works correctly (returns the tuple `(data, bounds, csv)`). However, when I run it in Flask it gives me the error  `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`. When I debug in Flask and print the value the function returns, it just prints the value of `data`:

```
>>> print(extract_data(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads', filename)))
[0.0476  0.07544 0.27416 0.04569 0.01261]
```

However, if I run through the steps of `extract_data` in the Flask debugger it also works correctly. I don't think there is a problem with `extract_data` itself. I've tried wrapping the tuple in commas, defining the tuple as a variable and returning the variable, and removing the type hint. I can use this function outside of Flask with the same data and it returns the expected tuple. The file upload seems to work just fine, and `csv` looks as expected.

Edit: I've also tried returning a list and got the same error. I also  tried assigning the list to a variable and returning that variable and got the same error.

**Relevant information**

`data` is a numpy array:

`[0.0476  0.07544 0.27416 0.04569 0.01261]`

Here is `csv`:

```
   bounds     data
0      84  0.04760
1    2483  0.07544
2    4540  0.27416
3   13822  0.04569
4   20075  0.01261
5   23400      NaN
```

and `n_intervals` is an int (5).

Here is the relevant part of the Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from app import app
from app.forms import MyForm

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        f = form.csv.data
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads', filename))
        data, bounds, csv = extract_data(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads', filename))
        return render_template('result.html')
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```

`MyForm` is just a class that inherits from `FlaskForm` from `flask_wtf` for the file upload.

I'm pretty stumped about this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you print extract_data function it gives 5 values , and where as they should be 3. Maybe there is problem in extract_data function which returns 5 values rather 3

Comment: @charchit Yes, I know. That's only the case when I run it in Flask. ```data``` is a numpy array with shape (5, 0).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Flask requires you to use absolute paths in `sys.path.insert`.

For example:

`sys.path.insert(0, "/full/path/goes/here")`

and not

`sys.path.insert(0, "~/path/goes/here")`

or

`sys.path.insert(0, "../path/goes/here")`

The function runs correctly when absolute paths are specified.